# Proof using mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Prove using the mean value theorem that $e^{x+1}\geq 2e^x$ by considering the interval $[x,x+1]$.

Using the definition, there exists a $c$ in $(x,x+1)$ such that $e^{x+1} - e^x = e^c$ (this is of course after simplifying the fraction expression). Now this is where I'm stuck. I tried using the fact that $e^c >0$ to complete the proof, but hit a dead end. How would I proceed with this proof?

Comment: Do you know $e^x$ is increasing? If so, $e^c \geq e^x$, and some algebra gives the result.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following:
$$e^{x+1}=e^x+e^c$$
Now, you know $c \in [x, x+1]$, so $c \geq x$, and thus:
$$e^c \geq e^x \implies e^x+e^c \geq e^x+e^x \implies e^{x+1} \geq 2e^x$$

Comment: Wow lol. I feel so stupid. Thanks heaps. I'll accept answer in 4 minutes (it won't let right now),